# Starting values for elo

Tags: algorithm, system, rating

Recently made a tournament bracket where players can sign up and participate in a chance to get the winning spot. As you can see, here is a picture of it:

[image]

Once the tournament bracket is finished, I plan to convert these winnings into rankings. So, as a result, "Achilles" would be ranked #1 since he did the best in the tournament, then #2 would be "rjg 2", and so on. The reason why the tournament bracket would be converted into rankings is because now I want to give players the opportunity of creating matches against other players. This is significant because even though a tournament bracket works, it does not contain the outcome of every possible match between the players. That's fine, the tournament bracket is just there to give others a basic representation of who is the best/worst. However, once the tournament bracket is converted to rankings, new users also have the opportunity to sign up, allowing for more players to compete against each other. Now, before I begin the rankings part, I want to attempt to use Elo ranking in the matches. My problem is, I need to assign these players in the tournaments points. This is tricky because If i'm not careful my K value can mess with the order of things. Here is my table:

```
#1 Achilles
#2 rjg 2
#3 gg
#4 beta 1
#5 dfgsdf
#6 test2
#7 rjgtest
#8 rocket
```

I need to assign each player "points" to reflect the rankings. This means #1 Achilles would have the most points while #2 would be rjg2 and so on... However, with the way Elo works, I'm unaware on how much points to assign. If I do it too ranged, the players won't ever have any chance to move up in the rankings, but if I do it too small, the ranks will be constantly altering.

For example, if I set my table up like so:

```
1  1000
2  900
3  800
4  700
5  600
6  500
7  400
8  300
9  200
10 100
```

Where #1 would have 1,000 points, #2 would have 900 points, and so on. If rank #10 beats rank #1, it's obviously VERY unlikely. So, when I do the math with elo, here is what happens:

So if I go about it this way (based off of the way it is explained [here](http://www.lifewithalacrity.com/2006/01/ranking_systems.html) ), lets say I have rank #10 facing rank #1. According to the website above, my formula is:

```
R' = R + K * (S - E)
```

and the rating of #10 only has 100 points where #1 has 1,000.
So after doing the math rank #10's expected value of beating #1 is:

```
1 / [ 1 + 10 ^ ( [1000 - 100] / 400) ]
= 0.0055%
```

0.55% is very low and makes sense, Rank #10 almost has no chance of beating someone as good as Rank #1. However, if he was to beat him, here is the result:

```
 100 + 32 * (1 - 0.0055)
 = 131.824
```

He would only gain 31 points when beating a player ranked as #1. This obviously won't work but I can either decrease the range in points or increase my K factor.

Does anyone have any suggestions to make this work? Or maybe suggest I rank my players a different way?

Comment: set `K` a bit higher. If he was able to beat the #1, he will surely win a couple of more times... you really don't want huge swings just because of a single match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't know much about Elo ratings, but I understand that choosing an appropriate K value can be problematic.

I know that often the K value is altered depending on *how many games a player has played*. A player who has played many games is given a lower K value, so their rating does not change too much (because we are more certain about their rating, we want it to remain fairly constant). Similarly a player who has not played many games would get a higher K value (we are less certain about their rating, so we don't mind if it moves about more).

One alternative approach is to use ratings systems which try to incorporate a measure of our uncertainty about a player's rating. For example, the Glicko rating system or Microsoft's TrueSkill algorithm. These systems build up their own estimates of the variability in (or uncertainty about) a player's skill level, so you don't need to set a K value.

There is a very good Python implementation of TrueSkill at http://trueskill.org, written by Heungsub Lee, with plenty of examples of how to use the library. A player's rating comprises a mean (representing their estimated skill) and a standard deviation (representing our uncertainty about their skill).

TrueSkill is used by Microsoft for matchmaking on many Xbox games, so should be a good fit for your intention of matching players of similar ability.

Comment: I understand the K value is very significant to Elo. However, I don't think it is AS significant in my system. Meaning, I don't think I have to make it a variable for different players, I think I can have it constant all over. But, I'm looking at any options possible. TrueSkill seems great but not as easy to implement as Elo. Thank you for showing me this though.